# How to parameterize a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

If I have $M$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $x-y^2+z^2=0$ and $y^2+z^2<4$, how would I find a function from $\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ ($d$ is the dimension of the manifold)that parameterizes $M$?

Comment: How about $(y,z) \mapsto (y^2-z^2, y, z)$?

Comment: Can you help me understand how you came to this?

Comment: It follows directly from your equation: $$ x-y^2+z^2 = 0 \iff x = y^2-z^2, $$ which tells you how the $x$-coordinate depends on the other two.